# Python 3 outputting weird arithmetic result

Tags: python, math

I was writing a calculator in Python and was working with handling exponentiation. I came across something very strange when dealing with exponents that are decimals, so I tried reproducing the problem in the console. This is what I got:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Oct 11 2016, 04:59:56) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> num1 = -3.0
>>> num2 = 2.5
>>> opr = '^'
>>> if opr == '^':
...     print(num1**num2)
... 
(4.772588574262081e-15+15.588457268119896j)
>>> -3.0**2.5
-15.588457268119896
```

Any pointers on how to avoid the first output and get the second one? I'm not entirely sure what the first output even represents.

Comment: All the answers point in the right direction: you're dealing with a square root of a negative number (a pocket calculator will simply throw an error if you try this operation). If you're trying to "emulate" a pocket calculator, then you should check that your results are not complex (and throw an appropriate error); otherwise, you can create a much more complete (and powerful) calculator that supports complex numbers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first output correct. It is an complex number, since you have decimal power of a negative number.

You can't reproduce it because, in the last line, you should write `(-3.0)**2.5`. What you have written is equivalent to `-(3.0**2.5)`, since exponentiation has higher priority than the unary operator `-`.

Answer (score 5):

The different output is simply due to the different order of the operations due to [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), use parantheses `()` to ensure the correct order is applied:

```
>>> -3.0**2.5
-15.588457268119896
>>> -(3.0**2.5)
-15.588457268119896
>>> (-3.0)**2.5
(4.772588574262081e-15+15.588457268119896j)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is not Python but maths:

```
(-3.0) ^ 2.5 = (-3) ^ (5/2) = sqrt((-3)^5) = sqrt(-243) = -15.588...j
```

As you may know, negative numbers don't have real squareroots. They have complex squareroots represented by the `j`.

When you are writting it directly to the console he is understanding another thing:

```
-3.0**2.5 = -(3^2.5) = -( 3 ^ (5/2) ) = - sqrt(3^5) = - sqrt(243) = -15.588...
```

The correct form to write it directly to the console would be:

```
<< (-3.0)**2.5
>> (4.772588574262081e-15+15.588457268119896j)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this can see if it work.

```
num1 = -3.0
num2 = 2.5
opr = '^'
if opr == '^':
     if num1 < 0:
        num1  *= -1;
        print ('-',num1**num2)
        num1 *= -1;
     else:
        print(num1**num2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second example:

```
-3.0**2.5
```

actually has higher precedence on the `**` operation, calculating something different:

```
-(3.0 ** 2.5)
```

What you are trying to calculate however is:

```
(-3.0) ** 2.5
```

which indeed results in `(4.772588574262081e-15+15.588457268119896j)`. That's a complex number, which looks like this after some rounding and simplification: `0 + 15.6j`.

If you don't understand why the result is a complex number, let's do it manually:

First, you can split `-3^2.5` into two parts: `-1^2.5 * 3^2.5`. The right side is roughly `15.6`, the number you saw above. `-1^2.5` can be expanded to `(-1^0.5)^5`. This is the same as `sqrt(-1)^5`. Simplify some more:

```
sqrt(-1)^5 = i^5 = i*i*i*i*i = -1 * -1 * i = 1*i = i
```

Hence the whole thing is `15.6i`. Note that in mathematics `i` is used for the imaginary part of a complex number, but in programming it's usually substituted with `j`, but they mean the same thing.